# useState variables are null in event callback

Tags: reactjs, web3js

I am working on a reactjs web application which interacts with a solidity smartcontract.

This smartcontract emit events and i want to listen to this events in my web application.

Here is my react js file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import getWeb3 from "./getWeb3";
import Contract1 from "./contracts/Contract1.json";

const App = () => {
  // Hooked variables
  const [web3, setWeb3] = useState(null);
  const [account, setAccount] = useState(null);
  const [contract, setContract] = useState(null);

 function callback(event) {
      console.log(account);  // Problem: Every hooked variables are null here
  }

  async function init() {
     const web3 = await getWeb3();
     const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
     const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();

     setAccount(accounts[0]);

     let deployedNetwork = Contract1.networks[networkId];
     let _contract = new web3.eth.Contract(Contract1.abi, deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address);
     _contract.events.MyEvent().on("data",(e) => callback(e)); 
     setContract(_contract);

     setWeb3(web3);
     ...

  };

  useEffect(() => { init(); }, []);

  ...
```

Everything works fine in my application.

callback function is called When MyEvent is emit from my smartcontract.

But there is something very strange: Every hooked variables are null in callback function.

I suppose this is a scope issue because this variables are set and works fine elsewhere in my application.

Comment: Is `callback` the same as `event_callback` used later? Where is `callback` used? I agree, it seems you've a stale enclosure of the `account` state in the callback. Can you share a bit more of what `callback` is doing with the `account` state?

Comment: I am so sorry, i have made a mistake. You are true: this is the same function i have edit my post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another useEffect to watch account and contract, then you can subscribe and unsubscribe when account change

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(account && _contract){
     _contract.events.MyEvent().on("data",(e) => {
        
     }); 
   }
    
   return () => {
      //unscubscribe here
   }
}, [account, _contract])
```

Comment: Could you explain please what the problem is and how this solves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answer suggests, the problem is the `init` function only executes once, we need to put it in the dependency array. To do so, this function and all the previous functions should be wrapped in `useCallback`. Then React will know when to rerun stuff and the hook objects will be filled.

This is how it's going to look like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
...

const App = () => {
  ...

 const callback = useCallback((event) => {
      console.log(account);  // Problem: Every hooked variables are null here
  }, [account])

  const init = useCallback(async () => {

     ...

  }, [//The proper dependencies of this function]);

  useEffect(() => { init(); }, [init]);

  ...
```

Comment: I unsterstand init is executed once. But init subscribes to a callback. When this callback will be called, account will be set